# I can't figure out where this NullReferenceException is coming from

Tags: c#, .net, linq, boolean

**EDIT** Upon further reflection I decided to amend my answer below to reduce the possibility of misinterpretation of the problem.

I am getting a `NullReferenceException` on this `IEnumarable` LINQ query:

```
designations.ForEach(desg => 
desg.ModifiedBy.UserName = userNames.SingleOrDefault(name => 
  desg.ModifiedBy != null && name.Id == desg.ModifiedBy.Id) != null ? 
  userNames.SingleOrDefault(name => name.Id == desg.ModifiedBy.Id).UserName : 
  "Not Available");
```

My best guess at the moment is that it comes from the following statement on the third line of the code above:

```
desg.ModifiedBy != null && name.Id == desg.ModifiedBy.Id
```

and the runtime is throwing a `NullReferenceException` on `desg.ModifiedBy.Id`. However, I "know" that c# truth-ness evaluations short-circuit (see, e.g., [|| Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346(v=vs.71).aspx)). Here, if `desg.ModifiedBy == null` then we should never get to evaluate `name.Id == desg.ModifiedBy.Id`. Nonetheless, this seems to be happening. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you certain that `desg` is not null?  Depending on what `designations` is, it could have a null element.

Comment: What if `desg` is null? Are you sure it isn't?

Comment: You're already accessing `desg.ModifiedBy` in the second line of your Linq query (without checking for nullity).

Comment: All good questions, but yea, I'm sure it's not `desg`.

Comment: can you show the definiction of ModifiedBy? your ModifiedBy obj may not be null, but ModifiedBy.Id may be.

Comment: Could the `name` be null?

Comment: @Habib, Why marking as duplicate when nobody even mentioned `IQueryable`? Why are you so sure it is an EF query?

Comment: @haim770 It's the only possible explanation for the behavior, and as the question is ambiguous as to whether it's a linq to objects query or not, and only one resolution of that ambiguity has an answer, it's a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: @Servy, Even if you're right that 'this is the only possible explanation', it still requires some clarification from the OP first.

Comment: @Habib, it actually is an in-proc routine. Kindly remove the flag. I'll edit the question

Comment: @haim770 Why?  It's the answer to his question.

Comment: @servy, haim770 is actually correct. The question marked as duplicate is *not* the same scenario as my question, since my question deals with an in-proc list

Comment: @Seebiscuit, What is `userNames`? Is it `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`?

Comment: @Seebiscuit If that's true then your code doesn't reproduce the problem you claim you have, and  your question should be closed for not having an appropriate reproduction of your problem.

Comment: We can't keep guessing what could be wrong. Post a [short but complete code demonstrating the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Get the answer in few minutes. Otherwise it will be closed as can't reproduce.

Comment: @Seebiscuit, I have removed the duplicate flag. But if it is for a LINQ to objects, I don't think *the* problem is reproducible

Comment: It could also be that `userNames.SingleOrDefault(name => name.Id == desg.ModifiedBy.Id).UserName` is throwing the NRE. Visual Studio can sometimes point to the wrong line (especially in nested `Func`s).

Comment: @stefankmitph Because question doesn't provide code to reproduce the problem specified and adds unnecessary discussion. Btw it is fairly simple to find why he gets NRE with the debugger.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel how you know when you can't reproduce it? and if you know, because _it is fairly simple to find_ - as you say - why don't you answer the question?

Comment: @stefankmitph Code provided isn't complete. It won't compile. And thus it is not reproducible. I said, it is fairly simple with a debugger and you have the code to reproduce the problem. We don't have the code to reproduce the problem but OP do. It is simple for him. If not, OP should have posted the complete code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Thank you all for your thoughtful insight. The answer was correctly provided by Vidas Vasiliauskas. And what do you know? It sometimes pays to have someone else look at your code, @SriramSakthivel, as "incomplete" as mine turned out to be.

Comment: @Seebiscuit I do believe others looking at the code will help a lot. But not a partial code. We need a code that reproduces the problem. Otherwise we'll be just playing the "Guessing game".

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the code above, while it will not compile in anyone else's   environment, and while it may not be the most illuminating, was enough to pinpoint the problem. And if you need proof, note that there's an accepted answer. I'm sorry if I'm somewhat curt, but I'm miffed about there being people who think the question is so poor they are willing to sacrifice one of their SO points to down-vote a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @Seebiscuit Accepted answer is also a guess. There are several possibilities in which your code could throw NRE. You should understand that guessing involves many people valuable time. In the end, sometimes we can't even guess right. That's why stackoverflow has a close vote called "Can't reproduce". Think of it, Is it good to waste everyone's time in guessing or how about posting a question with code to reproduce? Btw your question isn't a perfectly valid question as you claim. I think we should stop here, if you want to discuss more, start a meta question and invite me.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel feel free to continue this discussion on Meta, here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292318/2112866

Comment: @stefankmitph We know that he can't reproduce it for exactly the reason stated in the question; short circuiting of the `||` operator.  If the value being dereferenced were in fact null, then the code where it is claimed to be throwing a NRE wouldn't run.  This means that either the code isn't throwing where the OP claims, or the code differs from what the OP has shown.

Comment: @Seebiscuit The fact that someone was able to blindly guess the problem given both incompletely and invalid information to go on doesn't mean that the question reproduces it's problem.  It means someone guessed at the solution despite the fact that it doesn't reproduce the described problem.  Those aren't the types of questions we want here on SO; people just blindly guessing based on woefully incomplete information.  We want clear questions with clear, objectively  correct answers.

Comment: @Servy I appreciate your effort to raise my awareness of the issues in my question. To that end I edited my post, with an aim to make it less opinionated and to amend some of the more misleading elements (like the title). Thank you for all the time and effort you spent on improving our community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting null at value assignation

```
desg.ModifiedBy.UserName = userNames.SingleOrDefault(name =>
```

Comment: The OP is stating the exception is being thrown from a separate expression than this.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I changed my comment in response to the changed answer.  This isn't where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: @Servy How could he know that which expression throws the exception? Both are in same line.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel A different section would be highlighted by the IDE (it will highlight partial lines in cases like this where lambdas are involved), and the stack trace would be radically different.

Comment: Vidas, this has been an unusually involved post (with its own SOmeta counterpart, and all). I appreciate not only the fact that you answered my question correctly, but that you simply answered it . While there are many things wrong with my question, and I've thanked @Servy, among others, for raising my awareness, ultimately, its intrepid community members like you, that don't talk but act, that make SO special.